# gr-osmosdr Could NOT find Boost (C++ libraries)

Tags: gnuradio

End goal: Play about with RTL-SDR in GNURadio Companion

While following the instructions on [this page](http://sdr.osmocom.org/trac/wiki/rtl-sdr), I've run into errors concerning the Boost C++ libraries. While building the gr-osmosdr blocks to use in GNURadio, `cmake` fails to complete because it cannot find Boost which is definitely installed. Version 1.57.

```
Last metadata expiration check performed 1:27:21 ago on Thu Jul 28 15:01:40 2016.
Package boost-1.57.0-6.fc22.x86_64 is already installed, skipping.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
```

Specifically, the error message I receive looks like...

```
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Build type not specified: defaulting to release.
-- Found Git: /usr/bin/git (found version "2.4.11") 
-- Extracting version information from git describe...
-- Configuring Boost C++ Libraries...
-- Could NOT find Boost
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:125 (message):
  Boost required to build gr-osmosdr
```

The code in `CMakeLists.txt` concerning Boost is...

```
########################################################################
# Setup boost
########################################################################
MESSAGE(STATUS "Configuring Boost C++ Libraries...")

# Although not required on my system, some users have linking issues without
SET(BOOST_REQUIRED_COMPONENTS
    thread
    system
)

if(UNIX AND NOT BOOST_ROOT AND EXISTS "/usr/lib64")
    list(APPEND BOOST_LIBRARYDIR "/usr/lib64") #fedora 64-bit fix
endif(UNIX AND NOT BOOST_ROOT AND EXISTS "/usr/lib64")

set(Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS
    "1.35.0" "1.35" "1.36.0" "1.36" "1.37.0" "1.37" "1.38.0" "1.38" "1.39.0" "1.39"
    "1.40.0" "1.40" "1.41.0" "1.41" "1.42.0" "1.42" "1.43.0" "1.43" "1.44.0" "1.44"
    "1.45.0" "1.45" "1.46.0" "1.46" "1.47.0" "1.47" "1.48.0" "1.48" "1.49.0" "1.49"
    "1.50.0" "1.50" "1.51.0" "1.51" "1.52.0" "1.52" "1.53.0" "1.53" "1.54.0" "1.54"
    "1.55.0" "1.55" "1.56.0" "1.56" "1.57.0" "1.57" "1.58.0" "1.58" "1.59.0" "1.59"
    "1.60.0" "1.60" "1.61.0" "1.61" "1.62.0" "1.62" "1.63.0" "1.63" "1.64.0" "1.64"
    "1.65.0" "1.65" "1.66.0" "1.66" "1.67.0" "1.67" "1.68.0" "1.68" "1.69.0" "1.69"
)

find_package(Boost COMPONENTS ${BOOST_REQUIRED_COMPONENTS})

if(NOT Boost_FOUND)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Boost required to build " ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME})
endif()

ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DBOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK)
```

Probably just have to point one thing to another. But I don't know which to what.

Comment: Make sure the boost development packages are installed; these typically end in -devel.

Comment: If gr-osomosdr uses GNU autoconf, look in config.log for details.

Comment: Michael, no, it uses CMake and the error really is that it can't find boost this far

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to @Marcus Müller. It seemed in this instance it was the lack of the devel packages for boost. A simple...

> $ sudo dnf install boost-devel

...did the trick (Well, I mean it moved me on to the next failure).

Comment: "it moved me on to the next failure:" that sounds familiar (https://xkcd.com/349/)

Comment: Side note, RTL-SDR has an oldschool mailing list. I used it heavily a few years ago and got great feedback. Not sure how active they are today. https://lists.osmocom.org/mailman/listinfo/osmocom-sdr

Comment: You're right. Your answer helped me with building gr-osmosdr on OpenSuSE Leap, and then there are many, many "next failures". It finally worked though. My write-up is here: http://linux.topology.org/rtlsdr.html#install_rtl_sdr_gnuradio